# R : Return the name and the value of the maximum in a list

Tags: r, list, max

*My problem described in a general way (previous one with biology explanation below) :*

I have a function in which the results are written in a list. Each result corresponds to a different name in the list. My problem is that when I select the highest value in my list, I don't have the name corresponding to the result.

```
myfunction = function(parameter1,parameter2) {

tab<-list()

[...]

names(tab)<-c("A","B","C" etc...)
return(max(unlist(lapply(tab,FUN=max)))) 

}
```

How can I solve this problem and have both the value and the corresponding name ?

*Problem with all data (includes biology)*

I am creating a program with R for a class project which aims to determine the genotype of a DNA sequence.

I finished it but I have a problem to show the result I would like to have.

Here are all the previous steps to the last function I have a problem with :

- Data frame with all possibilities tested

  ```
  AA=c("A","A")
  CC=c("C","C")
  GG=c("G","G")
  TT=c("T","T")
  AC=c("A","C")
  AG=c("A","G")
  AT=c("A","T")
  CG=c("C","G")
  CT=c("C","T")
  GT=c("G","T")
  genposs=data.frame(AA,CC,GG,TT,AC,AG,AT,CG,CT,GT, stringsAsFactors = F)
  names(genposs)=c("AA","CC","GG","TT","AC","AG","AT","CG","CT","GT")
  ```
- Function to create a DNA sequence

  ```
  heterozygote=function(allele1,allele2, profondeur,perreur){
  autresNucs = c("A","C","G","T")
  autresNucs = autresNucs[autresNucs != allele1 & autresNucs != allele2]

  nuc3=autresNucs[1]
  nuc4=autresNucs[2]

  pallele1=0.5 - perreur/2 + perreur/6
  pallele2=0.5 - perreur/2 + perreur/6
  pnuc3=perreur/3
  pnuc4=perreur/3
  x=c(allele1,allele2,nuc3,nuc4)
  sequence_hetero=sample(x, profondeur, prob = c(pallele1,pallele2 ,pnuc3     ,pnuc4 ), replace = TRUE)
  return(sequence_hetero)
  }
  ```
- Two functions that are used in the last one

  ```
  proba_combinaison_hetero=function(combinaison,perreur) {
  hepallele1=0.5 - perreur/2 + perreur/6
  hepallele2=0.5 - perreur/2 + perreur/6
  hepautresnucs=perreur/3
  essai_allele1= genposs[1,i]
  essai_allele2= genposs[2,i]
  nballele1=length(which(combinaison==essai_allele1))
  nballele2=length(which(combinaison==essai_allele2))
  proba_combinaison_hetero=(hepallele1**nballele2)*    (hepallele2**nballele2)*(hepautresnucs**(profondeur-nballele1-nballele2))*(factorial(profondeur)/(factorial(nballele1)*factorial(nballele2)*factorial((profondeur-nballele1-nballele2))))
  }

  proba_combinaison_homo=function(combinaison,perreur) {
  hopallele1=1 - perreur
  hopautresnucs=perreur/3
  essai_allele1= genposs[1,i]
  nballele1=length(which(combinaison==essai_allele1))
  proba_combinaison_homo=(hopallele1**nballele1)* (hopautresnucs**   (profondeur-nballele1))* (factorial(profondeur)/(factorial(nballele1)*(factorial(profondeur-nballele1))))
  }
  ```
- Parameters of the sequence and creation of the sequence

  ```
   perreur <- 0.1
   profondeur <- 100
   allele1 <- "T"
   allele2 <- "A"

   combinaison=heterozygote(allele1,allele2, profondeur,perreur)
  ```

I calculate probabilities for each genotype which means for each couple of letters from the data frame "geneposs" (in a list) and return the one that has the maximum value.

```
genotypeselec=function(combinaison,perreur){

tab <- list()

for ( i in 1:10){ 

essai_allele1= genposs[1,i]
essai_allele2= genposs[2,i]
nballele1=length(which(combinaison==essai_allele1))
nballele2=length(which(combinaison==essai_allele2))
hepallele1=0.5 - perreur/2 + perreur/6
hepallele2=0.5 - perreur/2 + perreur/6
hepautresnucs=perreur/3
hopallele1=1 - perreur
hopautresnucs=perreur/3


if (essai_allele1==essai_allele2) {
  #homozygote
  proba_combinaison=(hopallele1**nballele1)* (hopautresnucs**(profondeur-   nballele1))* (factorial(profondeur)/(factorial(nballele1)*(factorial(profondeur-nballele1))))
  }
else {
   #heterozygote
  proba_combinaison=(hepallele1**nballele1)*(hepallele2**nballele2)* (hepautresnucs**(profondeur-nballele1-nballele2))*(factorial(profondeur)/(factorial(nballele1)*factorial(nballele2)*factorial((profondeur-nballele1-nballele2)))) 
}
tab[[length(tab)+1]] <- proba_combinaison
}

names(tab)=c("AA","CC","GG","TT","AC","AG","AT","CG","CT","GT")
return(max(unlist(lapply(tab,FUN=max))))

}
```

The problem I have is that when I use the function, it only shows the highest value but no the corresponding genotype (that are written in names(tab)).

```
> genotypeselec(combinaison,perreur)
[1] 1.106063e-06
```

How could I have a result that shows both the value and the corresponding list name ?

Thank you,

Charlotte

Comment: You should provide easy-to-reproduce toy-problems. We do not have your data, so we cannot test your code. In R, you can use default data frames like `cars` and `iris` or create random objects with `letters` and `rep(1:n, times=k, each=l)`.

Comment: And we are not biologists either ;)

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, I thought I shouldn't write all my code because the problem I have is only about the max function...I edit my question.

Comment: You can use `which.max` to get the index of the max, therefore also the name. Then return a named vector containing both in formations.

Comment: I was more thinking of something like `tab <-  list(A=1, B=2, C=3, C=4, C=5); max( unlist( lapply( tab, FUN=max)))`. same problem, only 2 lines, no explanation about biology ;)

Comment: I apologize for this, I added an other version, I hope it's ok... It's the first time I am asking for help here and I thought that nobody would understand if it was to general. But I learned my lesson and will no make the same mistake next time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
genotypeselec=function(combinaison,perreur){

  tab <- list()

  for ( i in 1:10){ 

    essai_allele1= genposs[1,i]
    essai_allele2= genposs[2,i]
    nballele1=length(which(combinaison==essai_allele1))
    nballele2=length(which(combinaison==essai_allele2))
    hepallele1=0.5 - perreur/2 + perreur/6
    hepallele2=0.5 - perreur/2 + perreur/6
    hepautresnucs=perreur/3
    hopallele1=1 - perreur
    hopautresnucs=perreur/3


    if (essai_allele1==essai_allele2) {
      #homozygote
      proba_combinaison=(hopallele1**nballele1)* (hopautresnucs**(profondeur-   nballele1))* (factorial(profondeur)/(factorial(nballele1)*(factorial(profondeur-nballele1))))
    }
    else {
      #heterozygote
      proba_combinaison=(hepallele1**nballele1)*(hepallele2**nballele2)* (hepautresnucs**(profondeur-nballele1-nballele2))*(factorial(profondeur)/(factorial(nballele1)*factorial(nballele2)*factorial((profondeur-nballele1-nballele2)))) 
    }
    tab[[length(tab)+1]] <- proba_combinaison
  }

  res <- max(unlist(lapply(tab,FUN=max)))
  names(res) <- c("AA","CC","GG","TT","AC","AG","AT","CG","CT","GT")[which.max(unlist(lapply(tab,FUN=max)))]
  return(res)

}
```